# react-native-windows ScrollView: View is not scrolling

Tags: react-native, uwp, react-native-windows

Tried using flex:1 style for scrollview but its not working

**Dependencies**

- react-native -v: 0.54.2
- npm ls rnpm-plugin-windows: ^0.2.8
- npm ls react-native-windows: ^0.54.0-rc.1
- node -v: v6.11.3
- npm -v: 3.10.10

**Development environment**

- Target Platform: UWP
- Target Platform Version(s): 10.0.14393
- Target Device(s): Desktop, Mobile (ARM), Mobile Emulator
- Development Operating System: Windows
- Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using DrawerNavigator as your navigator; try with StackNavigator. I think issue is with the app navigator.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue inside react native windows package. You can check following URL for the same. They have some workaround solution there.

[React Native Windows ScrollView Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1617)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also commented in that issue in GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1617

Comment: I think issue is with the navigator I used, after i changed the DrawerNavigator to StackNavigator it workes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scrollview there ...
First import

```
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';
```

Add in a view

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" bounces={false}>

</ScrollView>
</View>
```